# Is there a way to set parameters to Http Session on making HTTP GET/POST using Apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, http, httprequest, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

There is an API which is getting some parameters from HTTP Session.

```
String userName = session.getParameter("userName");
```

I am using Apache HttpClient. I am making a HTTP GET to that API with some parameters as query string. I am not knowing how to set parameters in HttpSession before making HTTP GET/POST using Apache HttpClient, so that the parameter I set will be picked up by the API. If there is way to do that, can someone suggest me the way it need to be done. Or if any other tool is capable of doing the same also is fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As a client, you cannot set values into the HttpSession used by the server's API (for obvious security reasons). There must be some filter on the server side that is authenticating the incoming GET/POST request and setting the "userName" parameter in the session. If you want to set this parameter on server side, then you need to use `ServletFilter`, `HttpServletRequestWrapper` classes to implement that in a proper way (you can search for these classes to get more information).